How to fetch the product data from sitecore content hub
Using sitecore xm cloud and headless architecture
Using content hub to store data.
Created a collection and created data under products tab.
I want to fetch the product items under that collection from next js.
Is there an API to achieve this

https://doc.sitecore.com/ch/en/users/content-hub/experience-edge-for-content-hub.html

You can use Content Hub REST Api to fetch items from Collection while using DAM module in Content Hub.
Method: GET
{{ContentHub_InstanceUrl}}/api/entities/query?query=Definition.Name=='M.Asset' AND Parent('CollectionToAsset').id=={{Collection_Id}}

This will returns all the items under the Collection by passing the Collection_Id inside the relation CollectionToAsset above.

Note: Above Api needs to be authenticated using OAuth Token. More details for the same can be obtained here.
https://doc.sitecore.com/ch/en/developers/cloud-dev/oauth-tokens.html
Similarly to get all the products under Product Family, use below REST API.
/api/entities/query?query=Definition.Name=='M.PCM.Product' AND Parent('PCMProductFamilyToProduct').id=={{ProductFamilyId}}

Using above way, you can retrieve items from the Collection.
Hope this helps!!!

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
